# How does the topology work of a Klein bottle embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ at the points of self intersection?

Tags: algebraic-topology, soft-question

How does the topology work of a Klein bottle embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ at the points of self intersection? Wouldn't the open neighborhoods look like copies of $\mathbb{R}^4$ there instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$? Thanks!

Comment: Who embeds a Klein bottle in $\mathbb R^3$? I thought the point of that illustration was that it is a kind of projection onto three dimensions of the actual embedding in $\mathbb R^4$. And then it's further projected down to $\mathbb R^2$ to be printed in a book or on the Web. You can illustrate a Mobius band in $\mathbb R^2$ too, but that doesn't mean there is an embedding in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Oh, it's a projection into 3 dimensions. Interesting. Something always seemed a bit wonky to me about it.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm sure the illustration is replicated in a lot of places without a full explanation. It's a good question to ask here.

Comment: The usual picture is a punctured klein bottle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Klein bottle $K$ does nor embed into $\mathbb R^3$. You only have an immersion $i : K \to \mathbb R^3$ which is locally an embedding. However, $i(K)$ is not a submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$ because it has self intersections. Each intersection point has a neighborhood $U$ such that $U \cap i(K)$ looks like the union of two perpendicular planes in $\mathbb R^3$.